# My transaction of 0.003 ETH from MEW shows "FAIL"

Tags: transactions, myetherwallet, etherscan

My transaction of 0.003 ETH from MEW shows "FAIL" in etherscan when checked with Tx.

The required Gas was set as 170000.
No reason is shown on the etherscan page.
What must've gone wrong?
Does the amount bounce back?
Need help.
Thanks

Comment: It said "Value transfer did not complete, most likely as a result of reverse opcode"

Comment: Do you have a transaction id?

Comment: A failed transaction causes an immediate reverse of the transfered value, you still have to pay for the transaction fee. If you are sending from an exchange or similar online wallet you should ask their support if the value was not credited value immediately. The recipient address is a contract without source code on etherscan. The only ones that can help you are the ones that created the contract, ask them for detailed instruction how to make a transfer to their contract.

Comment: Thats very kind of your Ismael.  I'll get in touch with the recipient party.  Have a bright day brother.

Comment: Thats very kind of your Ismael.  I'll get in touch with the recipient party.  Have a bright day brother.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between gas limit and gas price. Gas limit is how much gas you are willing to spend to complete your transfer, and gas price is how much each unit of gas will cost you. Gas limit is the gas tank, gas price is the fuel.

When your transaction fails due to a gas error, your ETH is refunded (it technically never left your wallet), but you will not get back the gas fee for the transaction. The failed transaction still required the miners to validate that the transaction would fail.